# default Text modification in azure ad b2c custom policy

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

in Azure AD B2C passwordless with email authentication/Password reset (custom policy ) first we need to enter email address and default test is **"Verification is necessary. Please click Send button"**.But after entering email address it lands to second page where we need to put OTP,
the message **"Verification is necessary. Please click Send button."** is also apperaing in second page also.
hoe can i remove it from second page??

[image: first page] [image: second page from where message need to remove]

I am using [this](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/passwordless-email) sample.

Answer (score 0):

just remove

display: block !important;

from div#email_intro css